# R ternery like syntax with truthy/falsy check of variable existence

Tags: r

I have an r script. I would like to test for the existence of a global variable. If it exists, assign to a variable, else use a fallback value. Tried:

current_date <- if(Sys.getenv('current_run_date')) Sys.getenv('current_run_date') else  '2020-10-31'

gives:

> Error in if (Sys.getenv("current_run_date")) Sys.getenv("current_run_date") else "2020-10-31" :
> argument is not interpretable as logical

Then tried with exists:

```
current_date <- if(exists(Sys.getenv('current_run_date'))) Sys.getenv('current_run_date') else  '2020-10-31'
```

> Error in exists(Sys.getenv("current_run_date")) : invalid first argument

I knew that probably wouldn't work. More generally, is there an elegant, less code way of checking for the existince of a variable and where it exists, use it, else fall to a back up? Like with JS: `var foo = window.somevar || 'bar'`

I would like to create the variable `current_date` and assign it the value of either the global variable described above else default to '2020-10-31'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Excel-like ifelse ternary):

```
current_date <- ifelse("current_run_date" %in% names(Sys.getenv()),
                       Sys.getenv('current_run_date'), 
                       "2020-10-31")
```

Or this (dplyr switch-case syntax):

```
current_date <- dplyr::case_when("current_run_date" %in% names(Sys.getenv()) ~ Sys.getenv("current_run_date"),
                                 TRUE ~ "2020-10-31")
```